# WebView Activity crashes if background image is used

Tags: java, android, html, webview

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_sukharta);
    WebView wv = (WebView)this.findViewById(R.id.wv);
    String htmlString ="<div id='MyEdit'><h1>आरती गणपतीची</h1>\n" +
            "\n" +
            "<body>सुखकर्ता दु:खहर्ता वार्ता विघ्नाची ॥<br>\n" +
            "नुरवी, पुरवी प्रेम कृपा जयाची ॥<br>\n" +
            "सर्वांगी सुंदर उटी शेंदूराची ॥<br>\n" +
            "कंठी झळके माळ मुक्ताफळाची ॥१<br>\n" +
            "<br>\n" +
            "जयदेव जयदेव जय मंगलमुर्ती ॥<br>\n" +
            "दर्शनमात्रे मनःकामना पुरती ॥धृ<br>\n" +
            "<br>\n" +
            "रत्नखचित फरा तुज गौरीकुमरा ॥<br>\n" +
            "चंदनाची उटी कुंकुमकेशरा ॥<br>\n" +
            "हिरेजडीत मुकूट शोभतो बरा ॥<br>\n" +
            "रूणझुणती नुपूरे चरणी घागरीया. ॥जय॥२<br>\n" +
            "<br>\n" +
            "लंबोदर पीतांबर फणिवरवंदना॥<br>\n" +
            "सरळ सोंड वक्रतुंड त्रिनयना॥<br>\n" +
            "दास रामाचा वाट पाहे सदना ॥<br>\n" +
            "संकटी पावावे निर्वाणी रक्षावे सुरवरवंदना ॥<br>\n" +
            "जयदेव जयदेव जय मंगलमुर्ती ॥<br>\n" +
            "दर्शनमात्रे मनःकामना पुरती ॥३<br>\n" +
            "<br>\n" +
            "<br>\n" +
            "<br></body></div>";
            wv.loadData(htmlString, "text/html", "UTF-8");
    wv.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
    wv.getSettings().setDisplayZoomControls(false);
```

If I use this statements the activity crashes.

```
    wv.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
    wv.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.or);
```

I used android:hardwareAccelerated="false" activity loads all fine but there is a lag.
Is there any other way to make use of background image for webviews

Comment: add logcat error

Comment: FATAL EXCEPTION: main Process: net.androidsrc.videosplash, PID: 13147 
java.lang.RuntimeException: Canvas: trying to draw too large(147456000bytes) bitmap.at android.view.DisplayListCanvas.throwIfCannotDraw(DisplayListCanvas.java:260) at android.graphics.Canvas.drawBitmap(Canvas.java:1415)
                                                                                at android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable.draw(BitmapDrawable.java:528)
                                                                                at android.view.View.getDrawableRenderNode(View.java:17432)

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/a/42495819/4063532

Comment: Actually my image size is about 70kb. Still the same issue